# Wrapping a TableRow in a Link tag in react-mui's table causes the entire row to render in the first column

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Table
  headings={['headingA', 'headingB']}
  // other details
  row={() => {
    return (
<Link>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>
            <Typography>
              {data.DetailA}
            </Typography>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <Typography>
            {data.DetailB}
          </Typography>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
</Link>
    );
  }}
/>
```

I've tried placing the tag in numerous places, as well as component={Link}, for some reason it keeps rendering the entire row under the first column.

I'm avoiding wrapping the tableCell, because it adds a padding automatically that makes area of the block totally unclickable. I want this link because I want to use the browsers onContext Menu, instead of making my own.